# Nothing happens when clicking on Create button while creating a new API key

Tags: content-hub

I am trying to create a new API key in my content hub instance using `https://xyz.sitecoresandbox.cloud/en-us/admin/api-keys`. But while hitting the Create button, nothing happens. It simply refreshes the dialog box without doing anything.

What could be the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After researching too many things, finally, I found the possible cause of the issue. There could be two reasons behind this.

1. Publishing is not enabled. We have to enable it from `Manage => Settings => Publishing => PublishingSettings`
   [image]
2. Publishing is not supported for your instance **region**. This feature is not yet available in the Asia region. You might need to create your ContentHub instance in either the **US** or **Europe** reason. Thanks to the Sitecore support team for this update.